# Find the user which repeats and match condition in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have table contains date,user,user_location like:

```
20120417 userA location1
20120417  userA location2
20120417  userB location3
20120417  userC location2
20120417  userA location1
20120417  userB location2
20120417 userA location3
20120416 userA location1
20120416  userA location2
20120416  userB location3
20120416  userC location2
20120416  userA location1
20120416  userB location2
20120415 userA location3
20120415 userA location1
20120415  userA location2
20120415  userB location3
20120415  userC location2
20120415  userA location1
20120415  userB location2
20120415 userA location3
20120414 ....
....
```

I tried several stupid method to find the users which matchs 3 days in a row, every day must had been at least 2 different locations.

Is that possible to use sql query to do this or I should try something like php script?

Comment: give some of those `stupid` examples?

Comment: Is that actually how the dates are stored? Or are they in a MySQL datetime type?

Comment: select and save to a new table in php, and recalc in php, .. too stupid to say here :(

Comment: @Ing it's timestamp actually.

Comment: It should be possible to do but it will tend to be a very complex query. MySQL does not provide easy means to help with this kind of stuff (for example, analytical functions in oracle can help here). therefore, if the amount of data that you need to copy is not that big, it is not stupid at all to do what you have tried. it is not necessarily stupid to do parts of the calculations outside the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works.  With MSSQL, no need to duplicate the derived tables.

```
SELECT l1.user,l1.thedate, COUNT(*) CNT FROM
( /* Derived table1: user,thedate,loc */
SELECT st.user,st.thedate,COUNT(*) locs FROM sotest st
GROUP BY st.user,st.thedate 
HAVING( COUNT(DISTINCT st.location) > 1)
) l1
JOIN
( /* Derived table2: user,thedate,loc */
SELECT st.user,st.thedate,COUNT(*) locs FROM sotest st
GROUP BY st.user,st.thedate 
HAVING( COUNT(DISTINCT st.location) > 1)
) l2 ON l2.user = l1.user and DATEDIFF(l2.thedate , l1.thedate) = 1
JOIN
( /* Derived table3: user,thedate,loc */
SELECT st.user,st.thedate,COUNT(*) locs FROM sotest st
GROUP BY st.user,st.thedate 
HAVING( COUNT(DISTINCT st.location) > 1)
) l3  ON l3.user = l2.user and DATEDIFF(l3.thedate , l2.thedate) = 1
GROUP BY l1.user,l1.thedate
```

Each of the derived tables identifies those days a user has 2 or more locations.